# Polynomial Factors of $f(f(x))-x$

Tags: functions, polynomials

Given a function $f$, it can be seen that the solutions of the equation $f(x)=x$ also satisfy the equation $f(f(x))=x,$
since
$$f(f(x))=f(x)=x.$$
If we choose $f(x)-x$ to be a polynomial with no repeated roots, then this implies that $f(f(x))-x=(f(x)-x)g(x)$, since $f(f(x))-x=0$ whenever $f(x)-x=0$. However, after experimenting with several polynomials, this result still seems to hold when $f(x)-x$ *has* repeated roots. For example, if
\begin{align*}f(x)-x&=(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1\\f(x)&=x^2-x+1,\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}f(f(x))-x&=\left(x^2-x+1\right)^2-\left(x^2-x+1\right)+1-x\\&=x^4-2x^3+2x^2-2x+1\\&=\left(x^2-2x+1\right)\left(x^2+1\right)\\&=(f(x)-x)\left(x^2+1\right).\end{align*}
Here, $(x-1)^2$ is a factor rather than just $x-1$. I also tested this with several other polynomials with repeated roots, and the result still seems to hold. Does this result hold in general, and if so, how can one prove it?

Edit: Fixed wording in the first sentence (thank you @lulu for pointing it out)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to prove that $f(x)-x$ divides $f(f(x))-x$. If we're willing to invoke polynomial rings, there's a very quick proof: let $S = \Bbb R[x]/\langle f(x)-x \rangle$, and note that $f(x)=x$ in $S$. Therefore
$f(f(x)) - x = f(x) - x = x - x = 0$ in $S$, which means that $f(f(x))-x \in \langle f(x)-x \rangle$, which means that $f(x)-x$ does indeed divide $f(f(x))-x$.

Answer (score 1):

> It is well known that: $$u^k - v^k = (u-v)\sum_{\ell = 0}^{k-1} u^{\ell} v^{k-1-\ell}$$

Let $f(X) = \sum_{k=0}^{d} a_kX^k$ then,

\begin{align}
f(f(X)) - X &= f(f(X)) - f(X) + f(X) - X\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{d} a_k \left(f(X)^k - X^k\right) + f(X) - X\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{d}a_k \left(f(X) - X\right)\sum_{\ell = 0}^{k-1}X^{\ell} f(X)^{k-1-\ell} + f(X) - X\\
&= g(X) \left(f(X) - X\right)
\end{align}

with $g(X) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^d a_k\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1} X^{\ell}f(X)^{k-\ell-1}$.